# Error accessing a service that uses DbContext on my quartz job

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, quartz.net

I am making a web API using ASP.NET Core and now I am having a problem with quartz scheduled jobs. The jobs I have will access my services to update the database. After some researches, I figured how to do the dependency injection so that my jobs can access the services, here is how I overrode the job factory:

```
public class AspNetCoreJobFactory : SimpleJobFactory
{
    IServiceProvider _provider;

    public AspNetCoreJobFactory(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }

    public override IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        try
        {
            return (IJob)this._provider.GetService(bundle.JobDetail.JobType);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new SchedulerException(string.Format("Problem while instantiating job '{0}' from the AspNet Core IOC.", bundle.JobDetail.Key), e);
        }
    }
}
```

and I added this line on my startup configure:

```
_quartzScheduler.JobFactory = new AspNetCoreJobFactory(app.ApplicationServices);
```

Lastly I added those two lines on my `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddSingleton<IUserService, UserService>();
services.AddTransient<BatchJobCheckContract>();
```

right now I am getting this exception when trying to execute the job, it seems like it's because my service uses the `DbContext`, how can I solve this?

> Cannot consume scoped service 'RHP.data.RHPDbContext' from singleton
> 'RHP.data.IServices.Administration.IUserService'.

Comment: Can you change `services.AddSingleton<IUserService, UserService>();` to `services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();`?

Comment: @Shoejep I just tried that, same exception

Answer (score 3):

After playing around with Quartz (version 3.2.3), it looks like you do not have to write your own `JobFactory` to use Microsoft DI. (See [ASP.NET Core Integration](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/aspnet-core-integration.html#using) and [Microsoft DI Integration](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/microsoft-di-integration.html#installation)):

Add the `Quartz.AspNetCore` nuget package and you can scoped services like this:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IScopedService, ScopedService>();

    // Job has scoped dependencies, so it must be scoped as well
    services.AddScoped<Job>();

    services.AddQuartz(q =>
    {
        q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionScopedJobFactory();

        var jobKey = new JobKey("job");
        q.AddJob<Job>(jobKey);

        q.AddTrigger(t => /* ... */));
    });

    services.AddQuartzServer(opts => opts.WaitForJobsToComplete = true);
}
```

However, if you cannot use the current version of `Quartz.AspNetCore`, you could still
use `IServiceProvider` as dependency in your `Job` class and resolve services there:

```cs
public class Job : IJob
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public Job(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var scopedService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IScopedService>();

        // ...
    }
}
```

Like this the `Job` class controls the lifetime of scoped services.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I am using version 3.2.3 actually which is perfect. I am trying to adapt to your solution now but I have one last problem accessing the services on my job, when I introduce a constructor that pass in the service the job doesn't seem to be called at all, how should I access my service if I am not using a new constructor ( ps: I used to solve this particular problem when overriding the job factory )

Answer (score 1):

I've previously had a similar problem with background tasks, you might need to create a scope.

I've adapted [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#call-services-from-main) code and applied it to your use case.

```
public class AspNetCoreJobFactory : SimpleJobFactory
{
    IServiceProvider _provider;

    public AspNetCoreJobFactory(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }

    public override IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        try
        {
            using(var serviceScope = _provider.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.
                return (IJob)services.GetService(bundle.JobDetail.JobType);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new SchedulerException(string.Format("Problem while instantiating job '{0}' from the AspNet Core IOC.", bundle.JobDetail.Key), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, the job isn't throwing an exception anymore but the dbContext doesn't seem to work, anything I try to access is empty or null. any idea why?

Comment: @YOUSFIMohamedWalid Hmm strange, I'm not sure, I assume you're using EF Core? You could check the connection string / check it's getting translate to SQL or that it's running on the db.

Comment: when I access the same methods on the same service outside the quartz job I get my data without problems

Comment: The code above disposes the `serviceScope` instance immediately. Disposing the scope disposes all resolved services, in particular the returned object and its dependencies.So your `DbContext` is not in a usable state.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianHeld that would make sense, though unfortunately I don't know how to modify the code so that it disposes correctly and still follows the OP's pattern.

Comment: @ChristianHeld what's the correct way to do it then? can you guide me